# Derivative of Neural Network - Cost Function of Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, neural-networks

I have a generative neural network model for the numerical simulation of a density matrix $\hat{\sigma}_\Omega$, where $\Omega$ denotes the set of parameters of the neural network.

I wish to optimize this network with respect to the Trace Distance between its output state and a chosen, fixed target state $\hat{\rho}$:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{D}(\hat{\rho},\hat{\sigma}_\Omega) = {1\over2}\|\hat{\rho} - \hat{\sigma}_\Omega \|_1 = {1\over2}\text{Tr}\sqrt{(\hat{\rho} - \hat{\sigma}_\Omega)^\dagger(\hat{\rho} - \hat{\sigma}_\Omega)},
\end{equation}
using gradient descent. Which means finding the derivative:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial\mathcal{D}(\hat{\rho},\hat{\sigma}_\Omega)}{\partial \Omega_i}.
\end{equation}

How does one compute this derivative? Can you perhaps using a chain rule like expression,
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \mathcal{D}(\hat{\rho},\hat{\sigma}_\Omega)}{\partial \Omega_i} = \text{Tr}\Big[ \Big(\frac{\partial \mathcal{D}(\hat{\rho},\hat{\sigma}_\Omega)}{\partial \hat{\sigma}_\Omega}\Big)^\textsf{T} \cdot \frac{\partial \hat{\sigma}_\Omega}{\partial \Omega_i}\Big]
\end{equation}
but I don't think this holds up when the states are (generally) complex? Any help/direction is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ease of typing define
$$\eqalign{
&w=\Omega,\quad P=\hat\rho,\quad S=\hat\sigma_\Omega \\ 
&F = \tfrac{1}{2}\Big(S-P\Big)\,\Big((S-P)^T(S-P)\Big)^{-1/2} \\
&{G}=\frac{\partial S}{\partial w} \quad\implies
 {G}_{ijk}=\frac{\partial S_{ij}}{\partial w_{k}}
}$$
The differential of the nuclear norm of a real matrix $X$ can be written as 
$$d\|X\|_1 = X(X^TX)^{-1/2}:dX$$
where the colon is a convenient product notation for the trace, i.e.
$\;A:B=\operatorname{Tr}(A^TB)$

Set $X=(S-P)$ and calculate the gradient of the distance function.
$$\eqalign{
{\cal D} &= \tfrac{1}{2}\|X\|_1 \\
d{\cal D}
 &= \tfrac{1}{2}X(X^TX)^{-1/2}:dX \\
 &= F:dS \\
 &= F:G\,dw \\
\frac{\partial{\cal D}}{\partial w}  &= F:G \\
}$$
Or in component form
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial{\cal D}}{\partial w_k}
  &= \sum_i\sum_j F_{ij}\,\frac{\partial S_{ij}}{\partial w_{k}} \\
}$$

Comment: Thank you so much! This is a great help. What (if anything) changes when considering Hermitian matrices in the argument?

Comment: A _complex_ matrix can be decomposed into 
its real and complex parts
$$C = A + iB$$
which can be collected into a single _real_ matrix 
$$R = \left[\begin{array}{r}A&-B\\B&A\end{array}\right]$$
with the following equivalences
$$\eqalign{
&C &\iff R \\
&C^\dagger &\iff R^T \\
&\|C\|_1 &\;\;=\; \tfrac{1}{2}\|R\|_1 \\
}$$
Using this, the above analysis can be carried over to complex matrices.

Comment: $\ldots$ and for the Frobenius norm the relationship is
$$\|C\|_2 = \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\|R\|_2$$